# Update Binding from DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate

I have a WPF with a DataGrid and I group rows (by "Name" in the example). I have a summary row for each group ("Name" and the total "Amount" which I calculate in a Converter). 
The problem is that I need to force binding update of the summary row but I cannot access it as far as it is in a DataTemplate.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource posCurrencyOpen}}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount"  Binding="{Binding Amount, Converter {StaticResource Amount_Converter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <DataGridCell Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        <DataGridCell Content="{Binding Path=Items, Converter={StaticResource AmountGroup_Converter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Many thank for your help.

Comment: Why and when do you "need to force binding update of the summary row" ?

Comment: `posCurrencyOpen` is an `ObservableCollection` of `Position` and I implemented the `PropertyChanged` event on `Position`. But when I change the `Amount`, the database is updated but not the "total" `Amount` so I would like to force binding update.
I searched a lot on the web, people said that effectively it won't update but no solution then.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I tackled it:  I had a Parent object that contained Child objects that were grouped by dates.  Each Child also had an allocation percent property (Pct).  I wanted to group by date and show the subtotal of the Pct fields so the user could make sure they totaled to 100%.  I inserted a TotalPct property on each Child object and then forced the Child to fire the PropertyChanged event for all of the Children with the same date.

```
    public partial class Child: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

    public double TotalPct
    {
        get
        {
            double ttl = 0;
            if (Parent != null)
            {
                var peers = from d in Parent.Children where d.StartDate == StartDate select d;
                foreach (Child dtl in peers)
                {
                    ttl += dtl.Pct;
                }
            }
            return ttl;
        }
    }

    partial void OnPctChanged()
    {
        if (Parent != null)
        {
            var peers = from d in Parent.Children where d.StartDate == StartDate select d;
            foreach (Child dtl in peers)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalPct");
            }
        }
    }
```

Then my GroupStyle bound the header to the TotalPct property of the first Child in the itemcollection:

```
    <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <cust:DataGrouper>
                        <cust:DataGrouper.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, StringFormat='MM/dd//yyyy'}"    
                                           Width="{Binding ElementName=detailsDataGrid, Path=Columns[0].ActualWidth}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="" Width="{Binding ElementName=detailsDataGrid, Path=Columns[1].ActualWidth}" Margin="-20,0,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="" Width="{Binding ElementName=detailsDataGrid, Path=Columns[2].ActualWidth}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].TotalPct, Converter={StaticResource percentStringToDouble}, ConverterParameter=2}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                           Width="{Binding ElementName=detailsDataGrid, Path=Columns[3].ActualWidth}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </cust:DataGrouper.Header>
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </cust:DataGrouper>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call Refresh() on your ICollectionView object.

Comment: Thank you, it worked with Refresh() and then I finally found the real solution. I needed to implement a `PropertyChanged` event on the `ObservableCollection` as well.